# How to deal with missing value in Tensor Flow prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensor

I have a group of players estimating the final score of a series of games and I wanted to see if a neural network would be more efficient to predict the real score than just taking the median of player's predictions.
My **data features** are, for each game, the prediction of each player, and my **target** the realized score of the game.

The problem I have is some players can not give their estimate sometimes so my tensor will sometimes have missing values. Is it possible to build a model with missing values? All the examples of NN I've seen so far were with complete data.

Below is a snippet of what data I'm dealing with:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
game1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Player': [1,2,3,4,6,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,28,29,30,31,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,43,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,58,59,60,61,62],
    'Estimate': [54,56,52,53,54,55,55,55,56,53,56,54,56,56,54,56,55,54,58,54,54,58,56,56,52,55,55,56,58,55,56,54,56,56,55,57,52,53,56,55,55,55,54,55,55,56,55,54,54,56,56,54,55]
})
game2 = pd.DataFrame({                                                                                                                                                                                          
    'Player': [1,3,4,6,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,28,29,30,31,34,36,37,38,39,40,41,43,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,58,59,60,61,62],
    'Estimate': [58,56,55,56,56,57,56,57,57,55,54,57,53,55,56,55,56,55,56,52,53,56,58,56,57,55,55,56,55,56,57,54,56,56,57,57,56,54,52,56,55,56,57,57,55,56]
})
game3 = pd.DataFrame({                                                                                                                                                                                          
    'Player': [1,3,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,17,18,19,20,23,24,26,28,29,30,31,33,34,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,46,47,49,51,52,54,55,56,58,59,60,61,62],
    'Estimate': [55,55,55,55,55,54,55,56,53,58,56,54,58,56,54,54,57,56,51,54,56,55,55,54,55,54,55,53,55,54,56,51,58,55,55,52,56,51,54,56,56,54,56,55,55]
})
game4 = pd.DataFrame({                                                                                                                                                                                          
    'Player': [2,3,4,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,26,28,29,30,31,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,58,59,60,61,62],
    'Estimate': [54,56,51,55,53,55,54,56,56,53,58,57,56,57,53,54,57,54,53,54,57,56,55,52,53,57,57,56,56,56,54,56,58,55,56,55,51,51,53,55,56,56,58,57,52,55,54,55,55,54,54,55]
})
game5 = pd.DataFrame({                                                                                                                                                                                          
    'Player': [1,3,4,6,7,9,10,12,13,14,15,17,18,20,23,24,26,28,29,30,31,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,43,44,46,47,48,49,51,52,53,54,56,58,60,61,62],
    'Estimate': [57,54,58,57,54,58,61,54,56,54,58,58,59,56,55,58,55,57,58,56,56,56,57,57,58,57,58,55,57,57,57,54,58,56,57,57,57,58,55,56,58,55,57,57,57]
})
game6 = pd.DataFrame({                                                                                                                                                                                          
    'Player': [1,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20,21,22,23,24,26,28,29,30,31,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,43,44,46,47,48,49,51,52,53,54,55,56,58,59,60,61],
    'Estimate': [63,60,61,63,62,59,60,63,61,64,63,59,61,61,60,61,61,63,63,62,61,63,60,63,63,58,61,60,60,61,61,59,62,61,60,60,60,64,60,63,60,59,60,58,61,60,63,59,61,60]
})
score = pd.DataFrame({
    'Game': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'Score': [55, 56, 55, 56, 57, 60]
})
features = [game1, game2, game3, game4, game5, game6]
```

This is of course just a sample, I have about a hundred games of data loading via a csv. AS you can see, each game has different dimension `[len(x) for x in features]`.
If I fill the missing data with NaN, how can I build a model that will ignore them? My intuition would be to set a first that works like a filter with predefined weight when input data is NaN but no sure if it is possible?

Comment: You should consider preprocessing your dataset using data imputation techniques to fill in your missing values. Judging from your dataset it seems quite straight-forward to build a matrix containing the data for all games and the score outcome (just assign one column per player prediction and one column for the score of the game). Once you have done that take a look at what scikit-learn offers here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html.